# Where are the python packages installed in docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker in my Mac.

Dockerfile:

```
#Dockerfile,Image,Container
FROM python:3.8

ADD main.py .

ADD test.py .

ADD spy511282022.csv .

RUN pip install requests pandas sqlalchemy

RUN pip list

CMD ["python","./test.py"]
```

My question is where are the packages sqlalchemy and requests located ,where are the directory ,because I want to modify some code of these package ,so I want to know where they have been installed.

Another question is ,can I customize the installation path and directory ?

Comment: If you try to uninstall them, it will show a prompt that tells you where they are installed to.

Comment: The packages are stored in the generated image. You have 2 ways to modify them: using additional RUN commands in your Dockerfile or copying the modified packages from your host computer using a COPY statement.